# numpy : Finding the tranformation matrix given 2 sets of 4 points in 3D euclidian coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, 3d

I am trying to solve the transformation matrix M (in its numerical form). Source points are known (s1,s2,s3,s4) destination points are kwnown too (d1,d2,d3,d4). Points from a pyramid.
The transformation is arbitrary and maps each point sn to its destination dn.

Obviously s1 to s4 and d1 to d4 are known and use numerical values, just presenting them like this for clarity

```
s1  = np.matrix([[s1x],[s1y],[s1z],[0]])
s2 = np.matrix([[s2x],[s2y],[s2z],[0]])
s3 = np.matrix([[s3x],[s3y],[s3z],[0]])
s4 = np.matrix([[s4x],[s4y],[s4z],[0]])

d1  = np.matrix([[d1x],[d1y],[d1z],[0]])
d2 = np.matrix([[d2x],[d2y],[d2z],[0]])
d3 = np.matrix([[d3x],[d3y],[d3z],[0]])
d4 = np.matrix([[d4x],[d4y],[d4z],[0]])
```

for each point, dn =  M x sn
with :

```
M = np.matrix([4,4])
```

the general formula seems to be here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Finding_the_matrix_of_a_transformation

I am basically trying to put this in code form, if possible reducing the complexity in order to use numpy linalg solvers.

I checked other threads, my question is really about the general case. (with the minimum number of 4 points needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but this can be done in two lines:

```
# set up

# create example affine trafo in homogeneous coordinates
M = np.r_[np.random.normal(size=(3,4)),[[0,0,0,1]]]
n = 4 # or more
# create n points as the columns of s
# note that homogeneous coordinates have a "dummy" 1, not 0, as last element
s = np.r_[np.random.normal(size=(3,n)),np.ones((1,n))]
# apply trafo, transformed points are the columns of d
d = M@s

# solve

# solving is as simple as
M_rec,resid,rank,sing = np.linalg.lstsq(s.T,d.T)
M_rec = M_rec.T

# you may want to inspect resid (should be small),
# rank (should be 4) and sing (shouldn't spread too wide)

# check

np.allclose(M,M_rec)
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can solve this problem by setting up a system of linear equations and solving it.

```
import numpy as np

# Setup problem

np.random.seed(0)
# Make random affine transformation
m = np.concatenate([np.random.rand(3, 4), [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]], axis=0)
# Make random points
s1 = np.random.rand(3)
s2 = np.random.rand(3)
s3 = np.random.rand(3)
s4 = np.random.rand(3)
# Compute transformed points
d1 = m[:-1, :-1] @ s1 + m[:-1, -1]
d2 = m[:-1, :-1] @ s2 + m[:-1, -1]
d3 = m[:-1, :-1] @ s3 + m[:-1, -1]
d4 = m[:-1, :-1] @ s4 + m[:-1, -1]

# Solve problem

# Arrange points as matrices of homogeneous coordinates
s = np.stack([s1, s2, s3, s4], axis=1)
s = np.concatenate([s, np.ones_like(s[:1])], axis=0)
d = np.stack([d1, d2, d3, d4], axis=1)
d = np.concatenate([d, np.ones_like(d[:1])], axis=0)
# Make equations (a @ x = b)
n = s.shape[1]
a = np.zeros((3 * n, 12), dtype=s.dtype)
b = np.zeros(3 * n, dtype=s.dtype)
a[:n, 0] = s[0]
a[:n, 1] = s[1]
a[:n, 2] = s[2]
a[:n, 3] = s[3]
b[:n] = d[0]
a[n:2 * n, 4] = s[0]
a[n:2 * n, 5] = s[1]
a[n:2 * n, 6] = s[2]
a[n:2 * n, 7] = s[3]
b[n:2 * n] = d[1]
a[2 * n:, 8] = s[0]
a[2 * n:, 9] = s[1]
a[2 * n:, 10] = s[2]
a[2 * n:, 11] = s[3]
b[2 * n:] = d[2]
# Least-squares solution to equations
x = np.linalg.pinv(a) @ b
# Reshape into affine transformation matrix
m2 = np.concatenate([x.reshape(3, 4), [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]], axis=0)
# Check result
print(np.allclose(m, m2))
# True
```

Using [`np.linalg.pinv`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html) (or [`np.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)) you get the least squares solution to the problem, in case the points are not perfectly matched. This solution works for any number of points. If you had a very large number of them maybe you could use a sparse solver. But in that case it might be better to use [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus) to find a good solution stable against outliers.